# Need regular expressions for username and password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex

I need help with two regular expressions (ASP.NET MVC 2 app). This is what I need:

Username:

- must contain at least one letter; digits are allowed but not required
- cannot contain spaces
- no special characters are allowed, such as `~!@#$%^&`
- underscore and "." (dot) is allowed
- cannot start with a space or underscore

Password:

- must contain at least one letter and one number
- cannot contain spaces
- are case sensitive

I tried with [a-zA-Z0-9]+[\w.]*[a-zA-Z]+[\w.]* for username but it failed for "a123456"

Comment: Have you attempted to make them - what have you got?

Comment: *"Password cannot contain spaces"* - Why?

Comment: I don't want to have "pass word" as a pass. Without whitespaces..

Comment: "Need help with" or "need to acquire"? Please demonstrate that you have at least attempted to write these yourself (perhaps using an answer to [one of the many related questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+password+regex)) and then ask a question when you have a specific difficulty. I, for one, shall not write your code for you (particularly if you are paid to write code).

Comment: I have this one for username, but it fails for "a123456"

[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\w\.]*[a-zA-Z]+[\w\.]*

Comment: @Mishko: That does not answer my question. I want to know why you care if there are spaces in the password. It was a rhetorical question to get you thinking, because the answer is invariably: You should not care. Let the users use any character they like.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Well I am wring a student project and have some requests that I need to fulfill like this one. I don;t know regexps, I tried to write this one up, but it failed. So I need help..

Comment: @Mishko: Okay. Like with coursework or exams, you'll get extra credit on StackOverflow if you show your working, even if you get it wrong. Please put that failed example from your comment into the question.

Comment: @Mishko you did not specify length of username or password.. according to your spec, one letter username and two letter password are valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex for username :

```
^[a-zA-Z]\w+|[0-9][0-9_]*[a-zA-Z]+\w*$
```

another regex for username , look ahead is used..

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)[a-zA-Z0-9]\w*$
```

Paolo's regex for password is okay, but you should put ^ to the begining and $ to the end of the regex to specify begining and end of the capture..

> UPDATE:

it is stated that username can contain dot character also. I have modified the regex , but I have assumed that username can not start dot character also. here is the modified regex;

```
^([a-zA-Z][\w.]+|[0-9][0-9_.]*[a-zA-Z]+[\w.]*)$
```

Comment: For username "1_aaaaaa" first regex doesn't work, but second one is fine, for now... Still testing...

Answer (score 2):

also you might build it here

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Gursel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328862/gursel-koca), this regex should do for the username:

```
([a-zA-Z\d]+[\w\d]*|)[a-zA-Z]+[\w\d.]*
```

([Regexr here](http://regexr.com?2tudv))

and this for the password:

```
([a-zA-Z]+[\d]+|[\d]+[a-zA-Z]+)[^\s]*
```

([Regexr here](http://regexr.com?2tubq)).

Comment: regex username is not valid , it can accept username without a letter.